# How to remove duplicate of user details

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a filtering system to show all users within a Wordpress site (they have signed up via the User Registration Plugin).

I want to show a list of all users, filtering by their company. I have managed to call the company on each li by using:-

```
.str_replace( ' ', '-', $user->user_registration_company ) .
```

However I am struggling to do this for the buttons that actually filter, as it displays company names multiple times. Please see full code below:-

```
<div class="networking-list">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'subscriber',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );                    
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        echo 
            '<button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter="all">'.str_replace( ' ', '-', $user->user_registration_company ) . '</button>';
        }

    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'subscriber',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );


    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        echo 
            '<li class="mix ' .str_replace( ' ', '-', $user->user_registration_company ) . '">' . get_avatar( $user->ID, $size = 280 ) .'<h2 class="filter-txt">' . esc_html( $user->first_name ) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html( $user->last_name ) .'</h2><h3></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>
</div>
```

So I basically want the button to show the user company, but only once so I can filter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are searching for is [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php)
Just load all companies into an array and run the function on it. All duplicates will be removed and you are good to go.

```
    <?php

    $companies = array();

    $args = array(
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users($args);
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
    $companies[] = $user->user_registration_company;
        }
    $companies = array_unique($companies);
    foreach ($companies as $company)
    {
        echo '<button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
                <button class="filter" data-filter="all">' . $company . '</button>';
    }
    
    $args = array(
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users($args);
    
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        echo '<li class="mix ' . str_replace(' ', '-', $user->user_registration_company) . '">' . get_avatar($user->ID, $size = 280) . '<h2 class="filter-txt">' . esc_html($user->first_name) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html($user->last_name) . '</h2><h3></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please show me how? I have never used this function before. Thank you choozn!!